Solving the calculus problem using intuition and not using pen
Given function $$f(x)=\frac{x^4}{(x-2)(x-1)}$$ and its third derivative is $$\frac{-k}{(x-2)^4}+\frac{6}{(x-1)^4}$$ what will be the numerical value of $k$?
This problem has to be solved not using any brute calculation so how should we solve this problem? Also if anyone is familiar with such type of problems please share it to us.
This question is very good example of not using brute calculation to solve a problem but to use a nice simple observation and simplifying the given problem to get the answer using very elementary mental calculation.(humble request to the community to not close this question rather look into the solution as I think most of the members won’t be able to to solve this question using the beautiful thinking. That is why this question should not be closed and kept as an example of solving problems in an elegant way.)

Hint: $\frac1{(x-2)(x-1)}=\frac1{x-2}-\frac1{x-1}$.

No this idea is still lengthy . Think something more intuitive and genius to solve it @AnneBauval

My hint - try to use the roots of a polynomial with repeated roots.

@Sillyasker this is not a forum.

Can you suggest some maths forums except aops to post such problems @SineoftheTime? Thank you.

I don't know any. You can write your solution/attempt and ask for different methods but writing a problem and asking to solve it giving hints is not in the spirit of this site. This is why the question is closed

Ah! I am very sorry. I didn’t knew it . I will keep this in mind @SineoftheTime. Thank you for the guidance.

@Sillyasker you can edit the question adding your solution and vote to reopen

Calculating $\left(\frac{2^4}y\right)^{(3)}$ is really not "lenghty" ;-)
